# How to change the log level for eclipselink in tomcat without code changes?

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, eclipselink

Sorry, if this is a dup.  Seems like it should be, but I didn't find it.

My logging works fine when I add the following to persistence.xml:

```
   <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="ServerLogger"/>
```

However, I would like to only turn this logging on occasionally.  Perhaps, turn it on only if there is a issue.

If there way to change this setting at runtime, with no code changes.  Note: I am using Tomcat and I use log4j for my current program logging.

GC_

Comment: How about create a custom Logger and act on it? (http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/CustomLogger)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ServerLogger, EclipseLink will default to your server's logging mechanism, but only if the ServerPlatform class within EclipseLink supports one.  Tomcat isn't a EE server and so you don't likely have a ServerPlatform class for it, so this is a meaningless property and will default to DefaultLogger which writes to the system.out.

You can specify [java logging](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging), but to specifically integrate with log4J, see the article [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/Foundation/Logging)